# IIS virtual directory and ASP.NET directory paths

Tags: asp.net, iis, relative-path

## The problem

I'm running into the typical virtual-directory dilemma in that you have some paths on your ASP.Net application and you deploy the app in a IIS virtual directory. Then all paths relatives to the "web root" (f.i., "/images") doesn't work because the app is in a virtual directory path.

---

## The solutions

**A.** Make the "images" folder a virtual directory. This way "/images" will always exist.

**B.** Use `"<%=Request.ApplicationPath%>/Imagenes"` as the source of my images. This works great in IIS but I can't see it in design-time nor in debug-time.

This solution also include these instructions:

- System.Web.VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute
- ResolveClientUrl
- Request.ApplicationPath

**C.** Use relatives paths to the current control/page. This is know exactly where the images folder is relative to my current file (without go to the root. So I would use things like "", "../", "../../" and so on.

---

## The solution I'm looking for

Said that. I don't like these solutions. I would want a solution in the web.config file or in IIS. Some conf intruction I write in the web.config file that tells IIS where my application resides actually (virtual directory).

Any advice?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Are you using the tilde (~) for your paths where you can?

~ refers to the root of the virtual Web application....

~/images for example.

Comment: alternatively, for non-server-side img elements, you can use the "/" character to refer to the root, as in <img src="/images/back.png" />.

Comment: @klabranche, the tilde (~) is for server-side controls and only usable in server-side code (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178116.aspx)



@DavidAndres, The slash "/" assumes your app is in the Web Site root (not for virtual directories). (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178116.aspx)
> A site-root relative path, which is resolved against the site root (not the application root).

Comment: @dealmo - I did say where you can....  I understand you are looking for an alternate approach to the one's you listed.  I was just making sure you have at least done what you can where you can. :)

Comment: @klabranche - sorry, and thanks. In fact I used it in a couple of controls. But I want to resolve it in aspx pages and css files :/

Comment: @daelmo: You're correct.  The images either need to be placed in inetpub\wwwroot\images or the src attribute of the img element should be updated to "/virtual directory/images/back.png"  Thanks for the update.

Comment: And there is no solution **what-so-ever** if I can't change my urls (because that would mess up when uploaded to production)?

Comment: I am using ~/App_Themes already, but it still resolve to the app root, not the virtual directory root, any idea?

Answer (score 3):

If it's just for css files on the client side then using the url directive makes the path relative to that of the style sheet rather than the page:

```
h1#title { background: url('dog.gif') no-repeat 0 0; }
```

Also if you're on asp.net mvc then you have access to:

```
<script src="<%= Url.Content("~/scripts/new.js") %>" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Comment: I use this solution without any path in combination with „Themes and Skins“, placing the images in the theme directory side by side with the stylesheet.