# Using relative paths with Web Api

Tags: c#, path, asp.net-web-api

what i want to do is to send images via my Web Api. Until now i was using absolute paths and the method Image.FromFile, then i converted the images into Base64 and everything was working fine. But now i uploaded my project and everything is working fine except for images, because the stored paths are "C:............etc" i tried to use relative paths like "Images/MyImage.png" or "/Images/MyImage.png" or "~/Images/MyImage.png" but nothing worked.
How can i fix this ?

PS
My problem is the same of this question: [IIS virtual directory and ASP.NET directory paths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449267/iis-virtual-directory-and-asp-net-directory-paths) but none of the solutions worked for me

Thank you a lot
Regards,
Marco

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Have you tried this?

```
string root_path = HttpRuntime.AppDomainAppPath;
string image_folder_path = root_path+"images";
/// Use the path
```

Comment: Thanks for helping, but where should i use this and how ?

Comment: I am not sure what you mean by that. see if my edit helps you

Comment: Man you are the legend !! That worked perfectly ! I wonder how i didn't find an answer like yours before ! Thank you a lot

Comment: yw. I remember I struggled it myself the first time I had this problem, there are so many ways to get the root path but this was the only one I found that act the same in both localhost and real server.