# IIS 7.5 not resolving relative path in JavaScript file

Tags: javascript, iis

I'm working on a simple JavaScript web app with a file structure of:

```
index.html
scripts/
  | main.js
styles/
  | main.css
templates/
  | options.mst
  | progress.mst
```

The JavaScript and CSS files are loading fine, and then I grab the templates with an AJAX call:

```
_.each(['options', 'progress'], function (templateName) {
  $.ajax({
    url: '../templates/' + templateName + '.mst',
    success: function (data) { templates[templateName] = data },
    error: function () { console.log('Could not load template: ' + templateName); },
  });
```

This works fine when I serve the site from Python's `SimpleHTTPServer`, but now that I'm trying to move it to a local IIS 7.5 server it's forming the template URL as though the JavaScript were executing from the root `/` folder, not `/scripts`. In other words I'm getting a 404 when it looks for `http://localhost/templates/options.mst` instead of `http://localhost/my-app/templates/options.mst`. Does anyone know why this is happening? I've looked at some related posts like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1449267/iis-virtual-directory-and-asp-net-directory-paths), but I'd rather not use anything IIS-specific in my code like the `~` operator.

**UPDATE**: I followed the instructions on [this](http://www.iis.net/learn/application-frameworks/running-classic-asp-applications-on-iis-7-and-iis-8/classic-asp-parent-paths-are-disabled-by-default) page to enable "parent paths", but I'm still having the same results.